# Client Side Validation of Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

**Visualforce Code**

```
  <apex:form>
             <apex:outputLabel >Subject:</apex:outputLabel>
             <apex:inputText value="{!caseTitle}" size="72" id="subjectId"/>

             <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!createCase}" id="submitId" onclick="validateSubject();"/>
  </apex:form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
 function validateSubject(){
            if($("input[id*='subjectId']").val())
               return true; 
           else 
               alert('Subject can not be blank');    

           return false;                      
        }
```

In above code, form is validated for presence of value in case title field. If it;s blank show error message & do not submit the form.

For some reason, form is always submitted, return value doesn't make any difference here.

What's wrong in here?

Comment: Is that javascript function is calling?

Comment: yes, its getting called & also showing correct alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created another button to click on real button if validation is successful.

**Visualforce**

```
   <apex:form>
         <apex:outputLabel >Subject:</apex:outputLabel>
         <apex:inputText value="{!caseTitle}" size="72" id="subjectId123"/>

         <apex:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitIdaaaa" style="display:none;" action="{!createCase}"/>
         <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateSubject();"/>
     </apex:form>
```

**Javascript**

```
  function validateSubject(){

       if($("input[id*='subjectId123']").val())
           $("input[id*='submitIdaaaa']").click();
       else 
           alert('Subject can not be blank');  


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine the else block:

```
function validateSubject(){

        xx = $(["id=*subjectId"]);
           if(xx!=null) 
               return true; 
           else {
              alert('Subject can not be blank');    
              return false;       
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to validate and then call your apex method from script function as below

In your page remove action attribute for command button

```
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitId" onclick="validateSubject();"/>
```

Then in the function call apex method

```
function validateSubject(){
        xx = $(["id=*subjectId"]);
           if(xx!=null) {

            yourcontroller.createCase();
            return true;
           }
           else
              { 
               alert('Subject can not be blank');    

                return false;
               }                       
        }
```

Comment: i don't think this is valid code, i will try this anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
    use bellow code
    <apex:page id="pgid">
    <apex:form id="fmid">
                 <apex:outputLabel >Subject:</apex:outputLabel>
                 <apex:inputText value="{!caseTitle}" size="72" id="subjectId"/>

                 <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!createCase}" id="submitId" onclick="return validateSubject();"/>
      </apex:form>
<apex:page>

And inspect element and copy input field id from console and place in place of id...

The element id should like this

"pgid:fmid:subjectId"

And place the id in javascript


function validateSubject(){
            if($("pgid:fmid:subjectId").val())
               return true; 
           else 
              {
                  alert('Subject can not be blank');    

                  return false;
              }                      
        }

It will work Any help feel free to revert back......
```